# How does ptrace POKETEXT works when modifying program text?

Tags: c, linux, x86, system-calls, ptrace

Does it bypass read only page permissions of the traced process? Or does it need to change permission temporarily to be writable? If that's the case is the permission change visible to the traced process?

Comment: My guess is that it marks the page copy-on-write and then writes it, so a copy is made.

Comment: You should be able to write a test program to answer the question of whether the permission change is visible.

Comment: @Barmar: In general, I'd agree with that advice, but here, if the change did occur, it would likely be very, very short in duration; and thus its detection is .. problematic. If that test program reports the change is visible, the result is reliable; but if the test program does not detect the change, it could be a false negative: the change could be so quick, it is only *rarely* visible. So, in this particular case, I'd recommend against testing, and instead poring over the kernel sources to find exactly what happens in these situations.

Comment: @NominalAnimal I was assuming that if it changed permissions it would be permanent. If it didn't use that mechanism it would just bypass permissions.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: yeah, agreed with Barmar.  The alternative to COW or a persistent permission change is to find the physical address and then use the direct-mapped portion of kernel address space to write that physical memory through that mapping.  (On modern x86-64 that region uses 1G hugepages to map all physical RAM.)  Oh, this is what your answer says the kernel actually does. :P  It would have to COW if the page is currently part of the pagecache for that file, though, because you're just modifying the private mapping of the file, not the file data.

Comment: @Barmar: Fair enough! :) It never even occurred to me that such a change might be *permanent*; even if implemented via the userspace mappings, the Principle of Least Surprise (one that Linus talks about often) dictates that the changes should only be temporary, and reverted back after each change. I'm well indoctrinated, it seems!

Comment: @NominalAnimal: I was sure it wouldn't do that, too.  Now I see the question said "temporary", so you were right, that's what the question is about.  So it's a reasonable question, because the answer isn't obvious if you don't know that the kernel can map the same physical memory with a completely separate mapping, and write it that way instead of futzing with the process's page table while it's potentially in use by other threads.  (Which would suck because you'd have to `invlpg` on all cores that could have loaded a TLB entry while the page was temporarily writeable.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the [kernel sources](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/), x86 uses the generic (as opposed to arch-specific) ptrace request functions.

The actual changes are done by [mm/memory.c:__access_remote_vm()](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/mm/memory.c), which uses [mm/gup.c:get_user_pages_remote()](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/mm/gup.c) to obtain the kernel mapping for the target page, followed by kmap(page),  copy_to_user_pages(), set_page_dirty_lock(), kunmap(page), and put_page(page).

The simple description of what is actually done, is that the target process memory containing the code is accessed (modified) thorough the kernel mapping — the virtual memory "window" or "barrier" between the target process and the kernel — and not through the mappings visible to user-space processes.

Based on the above, we can answer the stated questions:

> Does `PTRACE_POKETEXT` bypass read only page permissions of the traced process?

Yes. The kernel does not use the page protection mechanisms visible to userspace processes for this; it uses its own internal mappings.

> Or does it need to change permission temporarily to be writable?

No, it does not.

Note that except for the changed data in the userspace memory (and possibly whether the pages are backed by an executable file or not), and for any kernel or hardware bugs there might be, when and how the kernel uses its own mappings is invisible and undetectable to userspace processes.

Comment: Undetectable except via performance effects.  Re the last paragraph: Besides private file-backed mappings (like processes use for their executable + libraries), the kernel would have to COW if an anonymous page was shared between multiple processes after `fork` or whatever.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Sure, including instruction cache effects. However, I'm not sure if you can detect exactly *what* the kernel did (without a bytewise comparison); even if you can detect a change down to the page and cacheline. Typically the detection is also more statistical than deterministic: similar effects can (at least in theory) occur from completely different causes.  But I do agree: once again, I could definitely use better wording in the last paragraph!

Comment: @PeterCordes: I just realized that the performance effect due to a COW would only be detectable for the *first* `PTRACE_POKETEXT` to a code page. I'm not sure if the instruction cache effects (even whether an explicit icache flush is ever issued!) following consecutive modifications are measurable. Suggestions for fixing the last paragraph to use more precise wording are very welcome (from everybody else, too)!

Comment: x86 instruction caches are coherent with data caches, but architectures without that feature (and CPU design burden) would need an `isync` or whatever.  Interesting question, I wonder whether poketext has that built-in for the core that does the store at least?

Comment: @PeterCordes: I'd expect it to, but haven't checked any non-coherent cache arches (gets more work than fun fast, that kind of complexity; I do not usually remember any details, I just try to be efficient at finding them when needed). The kernel code is such that an arch implementation can easily utilize the generic paths, but then add their own flavor on top; even x86 does exactly this. `ptrace` seems heavily used among some devs, and seems well maintained, based on git and patch history. I've rarely needed ptrace, but when I have, it has really been worth the effort.